# Building Python: how to disable Py_LIMITED_API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, build

What configuration flags / make flags are responsible for this?

If I don't enable this, I don't have buffer APIs.  Not to mention it's not a good idea to make this a default... and that documentation fails to mention that using some of the Python's API is predicated on this compile-time setting...

Actually, it doesn't build with Python 3.5 either. I misread the diagnostic message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example of a `setup.py` will compile `foo.cpp` to have `py_limited_api` set to `False`:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    name='foo',
    ext_modules=[Extension('foo', ['foo.cpp'], py_limited_api=False)],
)
```

Make sure there is no `#define Py_LIMITED_API ...` before including the `Python.h`

You can test the existence of `Py_LIMITED_API` with the following statement:

```
#ifdef Py_LIMITED_API
#error Py_LIMITED_API is set
#endif
#include <Python.h>
...
```

**EDIT:**

You can compile the module by running:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

or by creating a wheel:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Comment: This is very interesting on one side... on the other side: it doesn't help. `Py_LIMITED_API` isn't set, but type `Py_Buffer` is still not available...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/miniglm/blob/master/src/vector2.cpp#L272) is a simple module of mine that exposes objects using the Buffer protocol. Compare it to yours.

Comment: That was entirely my fault: it should be `Py_buffer`, not `Py_Buffer`.